# Why isn't my css @keyframe animation working?

Tags: html, css, animation

For some reason, I can't seem to get css @keyframe animations to work whatsoever. This has been quite frustrating for me.

My non-working css @keyframe animation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNKBay

Code from it:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>This is a Test</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: testOne 15s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
   -webkit-animation: testOne 15s; /* Safari & Chrome */
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes testOne {
    0% { color: #1b1b1b; }
    25% { color: #f3c13c; }
    50% { color: #6feeae; }
    75% { color: #75adf9; }
}

-webkit-@keyframes testOne {
    0% { color: #1b1b1b; }
    25% { color: #f3c13c; }
    50% { color: #6feeae; }
    75% { color: #75adf9; }
}
```

It'd be great if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong.

*Thanks,*
- M

Comment: Replace `wrapper h1` with `.wrapper h1`, it's a class not an element.

Comment: `-webkit-@keyframes` - I don't know if it is a typo but that syntax is wrong. It should be `@-webkit-keyframes`. If you do this and the correction mentioned by Alexander O'Mara, your code would work as expected .

Comment: Thanks Harry and Alex. In the real code it is .wrapper, it was just a typo in this. I'll fix it now. I'll also try swapping around the @. I'm quite tired at the moment. Just making silly mistakes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It should be @-webkit-keyframe testOne{  }